# Distributing quantifiers in predicate logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

So I have two questions.

1) If I were to distribute the existential quantifier, would these two propositions be equivalent?

*∃x(Blue(x) ∧ Circle(x))* = *∃x(Blue(x)) ∧ ∃x(Circle(x))*

2) would the first proposition indicate that there is an *x* that is both *Blue(x)* and a *Circle(x)* or could the *x* of *Blue(x)* be distinct of the *x* that satisfies *Circle(x)*?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Edited* I accidently wrote "Bed(x)" instead of "Blue(x)", must be tired!

Comment: Those are not the same proposition- the first requires that x satisfy both $Blue(x)$ and $Circle(x)$, while the second requires merely that there exists an x that satisfies $Blue(x)$, and that there exists another (not necessarily the same) x that satisfies $Circle(x)$.

Comment: Thanks @Ispil !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would the first proposition indicate that there is an x that is both Blue(x) and a Circle"(x) or could the x of Blue(x) be distinct of the x that satisfies Circle(x)?"

The first proposition says that there is an $x$ such that both $Blue(x)$ and $Circle (x)$ holds simultaneously.

The second proposition says that there is an $x$ such that $Bed(x)$ holds AND there is an $x$ such that $Circle(x)$ holds. These $x$ values can be different.

So these propositions are not logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\Blue{\operatorname{\textsf{Blue}}}\def\Circle{\operatorname{\textsf{Circle}}}\exists x~(\Blue(x)\wedge\Circle(x))$ specifies that something simultaneously satisfies both Blue and Circle predicates.

$\exists x~\Blue(x)\wedge\exists x~\Circle(x)$ specifies that something satisfies the Blue predicate, and something satisfies the Circle predicate, but it does *not guarantee* that the same thing will do both.

You may now answer your questions.